# How to install an old version of Caret (troubles when installing the .tar.gz)?

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm running R 3.2.2, and I want to keep this version (a customized one). the latest version of Caret package does not support mine so i have to install an old one from the caret's website : eg caret_5.17-7.tar

when I run the install on RStudio i get this error :

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Fsociety/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unable to identify current timezone 'M':
please set environment variable 'TZ'
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'localtime'
* installing *source* package 'caret' ...
** package 'caret' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/RRO-32~1.0/R-      32~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/RRO-32~1.0/R-  32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="caret.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="caret.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'caret'
* removing 'C:/Users/Fsociety/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/caret'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/RRO-32~1.0/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Fsociety\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/Fsociety/Desktop/caret_5.17-7.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/Fsociety/Desktop/caret_5.17-7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What should I do ?

Comment: can you provide the install command that you used for installing the package

Comment: Hi, I used the interactive tab on rStudio to install it i just copy and paste the path on the package local installation

Comment: Odds are you need to install Rtools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: @KevinUshey i thing that Rtools is for building packages, I just want to install an archived version of a package

Comment: this is the command i tried : 
  pathToFile <- "C:/Users/User/Desktop/caret_5.17-7.tar"
  install.packages(pathToFile,repos = NULL, type = "source")
it gave a status 1 error